# What does Invalid_Field: mean?

Tags: c#

I changed the App.Config file to login.salesforce.com instead of test.salesfoce.com, Ran the program and now i'm getting this error. It obviously logged in successfully  because this error happens after the Login Method(). It doesnt really give me anything other than this.

Also, If i change the Value of the HTTPS back to Test.salesforce.com it works just fine again.

Any help?[image: Invalid_Field: Error]

App.Config Change

https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DFe0000000011j   < what it was
https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DFe0000000011j  < what it is

Comment: test.salesforce.com is for the sanbox and login.salesforce.com is for production or devloper org. I guess there may be some of the fileds in the sanbox are not there in the prod, so double check the fields in the query are there in sandbox and prod org

Comment: @Suri All fields have been double checked. The same query runs in production's developer console

Comment: post more code, the place in and around where you are making the change from test to login.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it didnt work. 
When i changed from test to login. I didnt realize that the Id at the end of the url would change. So after i changed this, the error went away.

Sandbox app.config URL
https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DFe0000000011j
Production App.Confid URL
https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/0DF40000000XdFa